# NSCollectionViewAttributes not getting applied correctly with custom NSFlowLayout subclass

Tags: cocoa, appkit, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewlayout, nscollectionviewflowlayout

I'm currently working on an `NSCollectionView` with a custom layout. For that purpose, I subclassed `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout` to top-align my items (which all have a fixed width what made the algorithm pretty easy). The problem I have now is that only the first nine items in my collection view get displayed correctly, that is top-aligned.

These top nine items are at least partially visible when the collection view is initially displayed. The other items that appear when scrolling down the collection view will be drawn without any top-alignment, just vertically-centered-per-row as the default behaviour of `NSCollectionViewFlowLayout`. By extensive logging I could verify that my Layout only provides `NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes` correctly modified for top-alignment.

When I resize the window containing the `NSCollectionView`, thus resizing the collection view itself, all items in the visible part of it will suddenly be displayed correctly.

What am I missing?

Here comes my custom subclass:

```
#import "MyCollectionViewLayout.h"

@interface MyCollectionViewLayout ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary<NSIndexPath *, NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *attributesCache;
@property NSInteger numberOfItemsPerRow;
@property NSInteger numberOfItemsTotal;

@end


@implementation MyCollectionViewLayout

- (void)prepareLayout {
    NSLog(@"Preparing layout");
    [super prepareLayout];
    self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(100, 138);
    self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5;
    self.minimumLineSpacing = 5;
    self.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
    self.attributesCache = @{}.mutableCopy;
    self.numberOfItemsTotal = [self.collectionView.dataSource collectionView:self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
    
    NSInteger numberOfItemsPerRow = 1;
    CGFloat computedSize = self.itemSize.width;
    CGFloat usableWidth = self.collectionView.frame.size.width - (self.sectionInset.right + self.sectionInset.left);
    repeat: {
        computedSize += self.minimumInteritemSpacing + self.itemSize.width;
        if (computedSize < usableWidth) {
            numberOfItemsPerRow++;
            goto repeat;
        }
    }
    self.numberOfItemsPerRow = numberOfItemsPerRow;
}

#pragma mark NSCollectionViewFlowLayout override

- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Getting layout attributes for rect: %f, %f, %f, %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    NSArray *attributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect].mutableCopy;
    for (int i = 0; i < attributesArray.count; i++) {
        NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = attributesArray[i];
        NSLog(@"Forwarding attribute request for %@", attributes.indexPath);
        attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];
    }
    return attributesArray;
}

- (NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!self.attributesCache[indexPath]) NSLog(@"");
    NSLog(@"Getting layout attributes for %@", indexPath);
    if (!self.attributesCache[indexPath]) {
        NSLog(@ "Not cached yet, caching full row");
        [self computeAndCacheAttributesForRowContaining:indexPath];
    }
    return self.attributesCache[indexPath];
}

#pragma mark Private instance methods

- (void)computeAndCacheAttributesForRowContaining:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary<NSIndexPath *, NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *allAttributesInRowByPath = [self getAllAttributesInRowContaining:indexPath];
    CGFloat minY = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    for (NSIndexPath *path in allAttributesInRowByPath) {
        if (allAttributesInRowByPath[path].frame.origin.y < minY) {
            minY = allAttributesInRowByPath[path].frame.origin.y;
        }
    }
    for (NSIndexPath *path in allAttributesInRowByPath) {
        if (indexPath.item == 9) {
            
        }
        NSLog(@"Changing frame for indexPath %@", path);
        NSRect frame = allAttributesInRowByPath[path].frame;
        NSLog(@"Previous y Position: %f", frame.origin.y);
        NSLog(@"New y Position:      %f", minY);
        frame.origin.y = minY;
        allAttributesInRowByPath[path].frame = frame;
    }
    [self.attributesCache addEntriesFromDictionary:allAttributesInRowByPath];
}

- (NSDictionary<NSIndexPath *, NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *)getAllAttributesInRowContaining:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSMutableDictionary<NSIndexPath *, NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *> *attributesToReturn = @{}.mutableCopy;
    NSInteger index = indexPath.item;
    NSInteger firstIndex = index - (index % self.numberOfItemsPerRow);
    NSIndexPath *path;
    for (index = firstIndex; (index < firstIndex + self.numberOfItemsPerRow) && (index < self.numberOfItemsTotal); index++) {
        path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:index inSection:indexPath.section];
        [attributesToReturn setObject:[super layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:path].copy forKey:path];
    }
    return attributesToReturn.copy;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `attributesArray[i] = attributes;` in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect :` and are returning the unmodified attributes.

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"Getting layout attributes for rect: %f, %f, %f, %f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
    NSMutableArray *attributesArray = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect].mutableCopy;
    for (int i = 0; i < attributesArray.count; i++) {
        NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = attributesArray[i];
        NSLog(@"Forwarding attribute request for %@", attributes.indexPath);
        attributes = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:attributes.indexPath];
        attributesArray[i] = attributes; // <---
    }
    return attributesArray;
}
```

Comment: Damn, so true. Sometimes the answer can be this simple. Thank you! Nevertheless, I don't understand one thing here: if I use the assignement `NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = attributesArray[i];` doesn't attributes hold a reference then to the object at index i, so that I always modify that item and don't need to put my modified result back - because it's already there?

Comment: If `attributes` is modified like `attributes.size  = newSize` then the instance in the array is modified. `attributes = …` replaces the pointer and now `attributes` points to a different `NSCollectionViewLayoutAttributes` instance.